Why is my query unsupported for List return type?
Entity Settings:
@Entity()
class Settings {
  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate: true)
  int? id;
  String key;
  String? value;

  Settings(this.id, this.key, this.value);
}

DAO for Settings:
@dao
abstract class SettingsDao {
  @Query('SELECT * FROM Settings')
  Future<List<Settings>> findAll();

@Query("SELECT * FROM Settings WHERE key = 'update_date_time'")
  Future<Settings?> findByKey();
}

Code:
SettingsDao settingsDao=sl.get<SettingsDao>();
    Settings? updateDataTime =  await  settingsDao.findByKey();

updateDataTime == null, but final allSettings = await settingsDao.findAll();. allSettings contains all my Settings entity. Why is updateDataTime null?
In allSettings list I have my Settings (6), one of which has update_date_time in key field. I add another method in my DAO to retrieve a List instead of one entity:
@Query("SELECT * FROM Settings WHERE key = 'update_date_time'")
  Future<List<Settings>> findByKey2();

Error:
E/flutter (23265): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Unsupported query "SELECT * FROM Settings WHERE key = 'update_date_time'" for List return type. It should be SELECT, since DELETE, UPDATE, INSERT returns `int` type.
E/flutter (23265): #0      QueryAdapter.queryList (package:floor_common/src/adapter/query_adapter.dart:53:7)
E/flutter (23265): #1      _$SettingsDao.findByKey2 (package:vr360newtablet/vr360_database.g.dart:892:26)

I tried to receive data via streams, it's null there too.
I am using Floor v1.5.0

This is caused by the name of table Settings, this is problably an "reserved word". There is two ways to handle this:
Fist: You can create your query add a double quote on your table name, such as :
@Query("""
 SELECT * 
 FROM "Settings"
 WHERE key = 'update_date_time'
""")
Future<Settings?> findByKey();

And the dart builder will handle this properly.
Second: You can change your table name.
